# Get the site access for the current user in infopath

Tags: infopath, user-profile

I have a save & close button on an infopath 2007 form, but i would like to create a rule on it to be disabled if the current user only has read only access to the sharepoint site, is this possible without code?

Answer (score 0):

If current user has read only access means that user cannot edit or add any items. Then why you need to set rule for your form?

Comment: Hi, because they can still open the form and then click on the save and close button which brings up an error. If i can determine on open if they only have readonly access then i can disable the button.

Comment: Hey how they can open edit form? Edit Item ribbon will be disabled for these users. will they open by giving the edit item url in browser directly? If so they will be redirected to access denied page.

Comment: They have readonly access to the sharepoint site, from there they can open existing infopath forms, once in the form the edit button can be pressed, this is a button on the form itself but of course if the then save & close via a button on the form they get the error

Comment: How users can open infopath forms from site?

Comment: huh, i don't understand that question, they just click on the existing form to open

Comment: If you created infopath form for any particular list/library, you can open that form from list AllItems.aspx page. In your case, read only users can't open any forms from AllItems.aspx page since they are disabled.